# Switch statement executes case 2 even after break

Tags: c

When case 1, the program executes the code intended but then when it asks you if you want to calculate volume again if you pick yes it just executes case 2. I'm not sure what's wrong. How can I get it to only execute case 1 unless the you pick 2 in the menu?

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        int main()
        {
            float menu1, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, t;
            int td;

            printf("Enter: ");
            scanf("%d",&td);
        switch(td) {
            case 1:
            printf("Enter a, b, c, and h of the triangular prism in meters\n\n");
            printf("a ");
            scanf("%f", &opt1);
            printf("b ");
            scanf("%f", &opt2);
            printf("c ");
            scanf("%f", &opt3);
            printf("h ");
            scanf("%f", &opt4);
            printf("\nWould you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
            scanf("%f", &menu1);
            if (menu1 == 2) {
                t = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (menu1 < 1 || menu1 > 2) {
                printf("\n\nUser choice must be between 1 and 2!\n\n");
                printf("Would you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                scanf("%f", &menu1);
                if(menu1 == 2) {
                   t = 0;
                   break;
                }
            }

        case 2:
            printf("Enter a and h of the triangular pyramid\n\n");
            printf("a ");
            scanf("%f", &opt1);
            printf("h ");
            scanf("%f", &opt2);
            printf("\nWould you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
            scanf("%f", &menu1);
            if (menu1 == 2) {
                t = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (menu1 < 1 || menu1 > 2) {
                printf("\n\nUser choice must be between 1 and 2!\n\n");
                printf("Would you like to make another Volume calculation (1 for Yes, 2 for No)?");
                scanf("%f", &menu1);
                if(menu1 == 2) {
                   t = 0;
                   break;
                }
            }
    }
        }
```

Comment: Please indent properly. It will make your code so much easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Your `break` statements [for `case 1:`] are *only* inside `if` blocks. If neither `if` is *true*, you get the fall through.

Here is your original:

```
case 1:
    // ...
    if (menu1 < 1 || (menu1 > 2) {
        // ...
        if (menu1 == 2) {
            t = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    // BUG: there should be a break here

case 2:
    // ...
    printf("Enter a and h of the triangular pyramid\n\n");
    printf("a ");
    // ...
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
case 1:
    // ...
    if (menu1 < 1 || (menu1 > 2) {
        // ...
        if (menu1 == 2) {
            t = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    break;  // FIX: this is your _missing_ break statement

case 2:
    // ...
    printf("Enter a and h of the triangular pyramid\n\n");
    printf("a ");
    // ...
```

Comment: Conversely, sometimes it _is_ legitimate to _want_ "fall through". In that case, where the `break` would normally go is usually replaced with a comment `// fall through` so the _intent_ is clear. Otherwise, it would look like a missing `break`, as you had. Helps during code review.

Comment: @UnEntitled you would have seen it not working if you had stepped through with your debugger.